# LimitRequestFieldSize doesn't exist in htppd.conf file

Tags: apache

I am using apache 2.4. I am trying to send data from esp32 to database, but I am getting "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand." after a quick google search I found out that I need to change LimitRequestFieldSize and according to google it exists in httpd.conf file but I can't found it. I also checked in httpd-default.conf file and it also doesn't exists there. Could anyone have a solution for this.

Thanks.

Everything what possible was.

Comment: Hi @thala52, welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is about Apache configuration, not about programming or ESP32s or databases. I've removed the esp32 and database tags from your question. Your question will likely be closed as "off topic" since it's not a programming question. You might get more help at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) as its focus is system administration issues (like Apache configuration).